# KeyError: 'Entity c does not exist in dfs'

Tags: feature-extraction, feature-engineering

when i try to run this code,

```
ftr_mtrx_custmr, features_defs = ft.dfs(entities=entities,
                                        relationships=relationship,
```

> ```
>                                      target_entity="transactions")
> ```
>
> i get such error，
>
> ```
> 490 featuretools.entityset - WARNING    index session_id   not found in dataframe, creating new integer column
> KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
> <ipython-input-82-d467a36d5254> in <module>()
>       1 ftr_mtrx_custmr, features_defs = ft.dfs(entities=entities,
>       2                                         relationships=relationshp,
> ----> 3                                         target_entity="transactions")
>
> 4 frames
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/featuretools/utils/entry_point.py
> ```
>
> in function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>            38                     ep.on_error(error=e,
>            39                                 runtime=runtime)
>       ---> 40                 raise e
>            41 
>            42             # send return value
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/featuretools/utils/entry_point.py
> ```
>
> in function_wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
>            30                 # call function
>            31                 start = time.time()
>       ---> 32                 return_value = func(*args, **kwargs)
>            33                 runtime = time.time() - start
>            34             except Exception as e:
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/featuretools/synthesis/dfs.py
> ```
>
> in dfs(entities, relationships, entityset, target_entity, cutoff_time,
>   instance_ids, agg_primitives, trans_primitives,
>   groupby_trans_primitives, allowed_paths, max_depth, ignore_entities,
>   ignore_variables, primitive_options, seed_features, drop_contains,
>   drop_exact, where_primitives, max_features, cutoff_time_in_index,
>   save_progress, features_only, training_window, approximate,
>   chunk_size, n_jobs, dask_kwargs, verbose, return_variable_types,
>   progress_callback)
>           225     '''
>           226     if not isinstance(entityset, EntitySet):
>       --> 227         entityset = EntitySet("dfs", entities, relationships)
>           228 
>           229     dfs_object = DeepFeatureSynthesis(target_entity, entityset,
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/featuretools/entityset/entityset.py
> ```
>
> in **init**(self, id, entities, relationships)
>            83 
>            84         for relationship in relationships:
>       ---> 85             parent_variable = self[relationship[0]][relationship[1]]
>            86             child_variable = self[relationship[2]][relationship[3]]
>            87             self.add_relationship(Relationship(parent_variable,
>
> ```
> /usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/featuretools/entityset/entityset.py
> ```
>
> in **getitem**(self, entity_id)
>           124             return self.entity_dict[entity_id]
>           125         name = self.id or "entity set"
>       --> 126         raise KeyError('Entity %s does not exist in %s' % (entity_id, name))
>           127 
>           128     @property

however, this returned KeyError : 'Entity c does not exist in dfs'
any idea what's wrong with my code?